# Problema em armazenar label de combobox em HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Possuo o seguinte combobox em HTML:

```js
var concelhos = $('select[name="Concelho"] option');
    $('select[name="Distrito"]').on('change', function () {
        var Distrito = this.value;
        var novoSelect = concelhos.filter(function () {
            return $(this).data('distrito') == Distrito;
        });
        $('select[name="Concelho"]').html(novoSelect);
    });


function mudouValor() {
      var elemento = document.getElementById('COMBOFAB');
      var texto = elemento.options[elemento.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("nome_unidade").value = texto;
 }
 
 mudouValor();
```

```html
 <span class="IWLABEL11CSS" id="IWLABEL7">Órgão: </span>
<select name="Distrito" size="1" width="195" class="COMBOCONCCSS" id="COMBOCID" tabindex="1">
<option value="00">Todos os Órgãos</option>
<option value="01">Câmara Municipal</option>
<option value="02">Gabinete do Prefeito</option>
<option value="03">Secretaria Municipal de Governo</option>
<option value="04">Assessoria de Comunicação Social</option>
<option value="05">Procuradoria Jurídica</option>
<option value="06">Ouvidoria Municipal</option>
<option value="07">Secretaria Municipal de Administração</option>
<option value="08">Secretaria Municipal de Planejamento</option>
<option value="09">Secretaria Municipal da Fazenda</option>
<option value="10">Secretaria Municipal de Saúde</option>
<option value="11">Secretaria Municipal de Desenvolvimento Econônomico</option>
<option value="12">Secretaria Municipal de Obras</option>
<option value="13">Secretaria Municipal de Ação Social</option>
<option value="14">Secretaria Municipal de Desenvolvimento Urbano e Meio Ambiente</option>
<option value="15">Secretaria Municipal de Esporte e Lazer</option>
<option value="16">Secretaria Municipal de Educação</option>
<option value="17">Secretaria Municipal de Agricultura</option>
<option value="18">Secretaria Municipal de Auditoria</option>
</select> 
<br><br>
                                    
<span class="IWLABEL11CSS" id="IWLABEL7">Unidade: </span>
<select name="Concelho" size="1" width="195" class="COMBOCONCCSS" id="COMBOCID" tabindex="1" onchange="mudouValor();">
<option data-distrito="00" value="00">Todas as Unidades</option>
<option data-distrito="01" value="01">Câmara Municipal</option>
<option data-distrito="02" value="01">Gabinete do Prefeito</option>
<option data-distrito="03" value="01">Secretaria Municipal de Governo</option>
<option data-distrito="04" value="01">Assessoria de Comunicação Social</option>
<option data-distrito="05" value="01">Procuradoria Jurídica</option>
<option data-distrito="06" value="01">Ouvidoria Municipal</option>
<option data-distrito="07" value="01">Secretaria Municipal de Administração</option>
<option data-distrito="07" value="02">FUNCAPI - Fundo Comlp. Aposent. Pensão do Servidor Público</option>
<option data-distrito="08" value="01">Secretaria Municipal de Planejamento</option>
<option data-distrito="09" value="01">Secretaria Municipal da Fazenda</option>
<option data-distrito="10" value="01">Fundo Municipal de Saúde</option>
<option data-distrito="11" value="01">Secretaria Municipal Desenvolvimento Econômico e Turismo</option>
<option data-distrito="12" value="01">Secretaria Municipal de Obras</option>
<option data-distrito="13" value="01">Secretaria Municipal de Ação Social</option>
<option data-distrito="13" value="02">Fundo Municipal de Assistência Social</option>
<option data-distrito="13" value="03">Fundo Municipal dos Direitos da Criança e do Adolescente</option>
<option data-distrito="14" value="01">Secretaria Municipal de Desenvolvimento Urbano e Meio Ambiente</option>
<option data-distrito="15" value="01">Secretaria Municipal de Esporte e Lazer</option>
<option data-distrito="16" value="01">Fundo de Manutenção do Ensino Fundamental de Valorização do Magisterio - FUNDEF</option>
<option data-distrito="16" value="02">Secretaria Municipal de Educação</option>                                        
<option data-distrito="17" value="01">Secretaria Municipal de Agricultura e Abastecimento</option>
<option data-distrito="18" value="01">Secretaria Municipal e Auditoria Interna e Controladoria</option>
</select>
```

Esperava que em label recebesse o label do combobox, porém não está acontecendo, qual seria o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta você chamar a função que criou no evento `onchange` do seu select. 
Tirei o type hidden do seu input apenas para exibir o resultado.

```js
function mudouValor() {
      var elemento = document.getElementById('COMBOFAB');
      var texto = elemento.options[elemento.selectedIndex].innerHTML;      
      //altera o valor do campo cujo o id seja igual a "label"
      document.getElementById("label").value = texto;
 }
 
 mudouValor();
```

```html
<span class="IWLABEL11CSS" id="IWLABEL7">Mês da emissão: </span>
<select name="Mes" size="1" width="180" class="COMBODISTCSS" id="COMBOFAB" tabindex="1" onchange="mudouValor();">
  <option value="1" selected>Janeiro</option>
  <option value="2">Fevereiro</option>
  <option value="3">Março</option>
  <option value="4">Abril</option>
  <option value="5">Maio</option>
  <option value="6">Junho</option>
  <option value="7">Julho</option>
  <option value="8">Agosto</option>
  <option value="9">Setembro</option>
  <option value="10">Outubro</option>
  <option value="11">Novembro</option>
  <option value="12">Dezembro</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="label" id="label" readonly/>
```

Comment: eita ferro kkkkkk como eu não percebi isso? muito obrigado!

Comment: poderia tirar mais uma duvida rapidinho? como faço pra começar com Janeiro selecionado?

Comment: Adicione o atributo selected na option dele

Comment: <option selected value="1">Janeiro</option> ?

Comment: Isso, mas repare que não irá disparar o onchange para popular o seu ipunt

Comment: e como seria possível dispara-lo?

Comment: Você pode simplesmente adicionar o selected na option e chamar a sua  função `mudouValor()`, por exemplo no load da página. Veja a edição da minha resposta.

Comment: Caso ao invés de ser um text, eu precisar ativar um outro combobox, será desta mesma maneira(disparando logo no load da pagina)?

Comment: Não entendi exatamente o que você quer fazer

Comment: Suponha que para cada mês teremos 3 opções diferentes para ser selecionado no segundo combobox, selecionou Janeiro, o segundo combobox vai aparecer A, B e C, selecionou fevereiro, vai aparecer D, E e F... isso eu já consegui fazer, só falta disparar no load da página, já começar com janeiro (já estou chamando a função da mesma forma que o exemplo)

Comment: editei lá na pergunta, mas não consegui fazer funcionar aqui... mas na minha aplicação tá funcionando

Comment: Essa já é uma pergunta totalmente diferente e ainda pode ser considerada muito ampla.